# How to eliminate all Total AV files / running in task manager as amsprotectedservice / antimalware SDK protected services / end task is denied

Tags: windows-10, task-manager, anti-malware

Running Windows 10. Total AV antimalware --- How to completely eliminate program and all residual files. I removed via uninstall however aspects of the program still remain and are showing as running in task manager as "amsprotectedservice" and under that is: "SDK protected services". "End Task" is denied, properties will not show. This program is messing with my computer. Constant pop-ups to download program and I've gone in and blocked renewal notices, though I never downloaded the program to begin with, and it is still running in task manager. This program is like an octopus and has tentacles all over my computer. How do I get rid of it without crashing my system? Please advise.

Comment: this application appears to be legitimate software so it should have an uninstaller (likely in add/remove programs). why haven't you tried to uninstall it? note that it is common and expected for AV systems to have unkillable processes. theres little point to an antimalware system if the malware can just turn it off...

Comment: As above:  "I removed via uninstall"  Please read before advising something that has been done. Thank you! I uninstalled in settings / aps: uninstall, defaults, optional features. The full program remains in my programs list also though I used settings to uninstall.

Answer (score 1):

I would suggest the following:

- Install again Total AV
- Download and install
  [Revo Uninstaller Freeware](https://www.revouninstaller.com/revo-uninstaller-free-download/)
- [Boot into Safe mode](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/start-your-pc-in-safe-mode-in-windows-92c27cff-db89-8644-1ce4-b3e5e56fe234)
- Use Revo to uninstall Total AV, using the Advanced scan following
  the uninstall and delete everything it finds
- Boot again into Normal mode.

Comment: Thank you harrymc. I will try what you have suggested.